# QML: How to set coordinates inside Repeater

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have an issue with setting coordinates inside Repeater:

```
import QtQuick

Window {
   id: mainWindow
   property int wi: 640
   property int he: 500
   width: wi
   height: he
   visible: true
   title: qsTr("Game")

Rectangle {
    id: gameWindow
    width: wi/1.6
    height: he
    anchors.right: parent.right
    visible: true
    color: "black"
    clip: true

    Grid {
        id: gameGrid
        columns: 25
        spacing: 0
        rows: 32
        anchors.fill: parent

        Repeater {
            model: 600

            Rectangle {
                width: wi/40
                height: 20
                border.width: 2
                color: "grey"
            }
        }
    }

    Grid {
        id: sGrid
        columns: gameGrid.columns
        spacing: gameGrid.spacing
        rows: gameGrid.rows
        anchors.fill: gameGrid

        Repeater {
            model: 5
           
            Rectangle {

            //                 anchors.horizontalCenter: sGrid.horizontalCenter
            //                 anchors.verticalCenter: sGrid.verticalCenter
            //                 x: (wi/2) + (index * (wi/40) )
            //                 y: he/2
               width: wi/40
               height: 20
               border.width: 1
               color: "red"
            }
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

Whole code above, but my question is about the second Repeater with 5 Rectangles.
I have tried to solve that with many ways. Most obvious seemed to me placing coordinates inside Repeater, but now I know it does not work like this - I have to place coordinates somehow inside Rectangle. I have commented code, where are the ways I have tried to solve this.

Anchors work very well - it places the first element exactly where I am expecting.
Problem appears with the next elements. They are placing inside the same element of Grid. I do not understand why the coordinates does not working. Documentation shows I could use "index", don't know, maybe the point is that's "read only" property? I have tried to set Rectangle with prefix "delegate:" with the same result as well.

Comment: I don't understand where you actually want those Rectangles to be drawn. But you're repeating them inside of a Grid, so the Grid will automatically try to place them for you. It's not a good idea to try to manually position them at the same time.

Comment: I need to start draw it in the middle of Grid (and it works with anchors), and place the next Rectangles one by one: on top of grid elements - from left to righ. Each Grid and Rectangle element has the same dimmensions - the point is I don't know how to add its value to initial coordinates (anchors)

Comment: Grid places only the first element, according to anchors. Even I guess it places all elements at the same Grid point. So I think, I need something like a loop equivalent. Documentation says it is possible to use "index" but it is not working.

Comment: @Mstfktr1983 please avoid unnecessary and distracting text that do not contribute anything to understanding the problem. focus better on explaining the real problem. Your question is unclear

Comment: Try to create an image showing what you want to achieve. If you want to fill a `Grid` from the inside it might not be the best idea to use a `Grid`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you mention you have `Grid` + `Repeater` + `Rectangle`. I am not sure what you want to achieve, but, it feels like you may have better luck by going `GridView` + `Rectangle` because `GridView` supports a model.

Since you want coordinate control of your `Rectangles`, it is possible to do this alone with `Repeater` + `Rectangle`. No need for `Grid` since the `Grid` will impact the coordinate system of your `Rectangle`.

Below illustrates how you can use a simple `ListModel` to control the placement of your `Rectangles`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Repeater {
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { p:100; q:100; w:50; h:50; c:"red"; o:0 }
            ListElement { p:200; q:100; w:50; h:50; c:"green"; o:15 }
            ListElement { p:300; q:200; w:50; h:50; c:"blue"; o:30 }
            ListElement { p:300; q:300; w:50; h:50; c:"orange"; o:45 }
            ListElement { p:200; q:400; w:50; h:50; c:"purple"; o:60 }
        }
        delegate: Rectangle {
            x: p
            y: q
            width: w
            height: h
            color: c
            rotation: o
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACaHichZHPTsMwDMbveQprD4C6dePgHRE3kBhvUFqriUjjLHNV0NR3J/0jsUyF+uDYX6Sfv8Sm8RwETnJqTfmpTNI+PLGTwPai3oqa4Kogxjt5KoTC3A7RcEUW4cVc5HUob66GGPRnSw05gSt43GbZEc7T0eEhZj3mEjeBqs0RGDPo/0Xs/kbUgciNkO1hhZJPlN0C5cO2NELyNSszJF+AcChcPWH2a17mF+0XML4N3k6Yx1s3v1X8c6rjUjBup5Q41NLdDr4QfCJ8I5wToTOVaIQuETWZWguCTtSSLQeEMhEDSyGGHQLfOexVr34A1GWa2A==)

[EDIT]

With the following, it shows how you could use `index` in 10 delegates to place your rectangles using a formula:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Repeater {
        model: 10
        delegate: Rectangle {
            x: 100 + (index % 4) * 100
            y: 100 + Math.floor(index / 4) * 100
            width: 50
            height: 50
            color: ["green","red","orange","blue","purple"][index%5]
            rotation: index * 10
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: index
                color: "white"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAB7nicbVDBTsMwDL33K6xIk2CgMiR26ZUTBySGuE07hNY00bK48lytCPXfcaCghfIOif3ynmPbHzpigY1sel/vC5+l5T1FYQrH4sm2CB8FKJ6xQyvIU5pwoAZDBberX0ZzbFVVqbwWG9uAZ/qEIelXcAUXPjY4wALuLmGZuEz2/iN7tOLKt0DEk+Hmf8PJN+IqWOesQ986mdE1BeIKtqZlxGiuDWOjJ7F2jBq8hj5dXc9dQLPbfv28WO+yIkxixVOs4Lux5fkiEl5wkD/TJ9hYO+JjWWPUdT6ov7Os8Uwo6p+Kz96mCczJeUGTPY9FHo3F+AnHvHre)

Comment: Thanks Stephen! Code above shows how it works! Could you tell me please, is there an opportunity to create Rectangles above with For Loop, using current loop index as coordinates? When I'm trying this with  "for (var = 0; i < 9; i++) {code above}" it does not work somehow.

Comment: Repeater + Rectangle using index in the delegate supplied.